# Passing a config file into a custom library codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I was reading in the Codeigniter user guide and [they say that](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html):

> You can also pass parameters stored in a config file. Simply create a config file named identically to the class file name and store it in your application/config/ folder. Note that if you dynamically pass parameters as described above, the config file option will not be available.

I have a config file set up with the identical name as my library and I am wondering how I can access the contents of that file. Do I need to load the config before loading the lib? Do all of the variables need to be elements of an array?

examples:

-- Config file --

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
$var1 = "Variable 1";
$var2['name'] = "foo";
$var2['title']= "bar";
$var2['content'] = "Lorem ipsm dolar sit imut";
```

-- Library file --

```
class Library 
{
    var $data;
    function __construct($data)
    {
            $this->data = $data;
    }
}
```

-- Then something along the lines of --

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library("library");
}
function index()
{
    var_dump($this->library->data);
}
```

(Yes I figure the name Library is reserved but this is an example)

Shouldn't the var_dump simply dump the contents of the config file? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try getting the config data with `$this->config->item('name');` - And i think you need arrays. So `$var = "variable";` won't work.

Comment: So you're speaking in terms of outside of the library, load the config and retrieve the variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things to make this work :

Your classname FILE should start with a capital letter, Your config array must be defined as `$config = array()` (and not `$var` or any other name), Your config file must be lowercase.

The config file is passed through the constructor, so `class($config=array())`, you can then access and store the config variables on an instance variable.

hope it helps:

```
class Foo // Foo.php
{
    function __construct($config=array())
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

} //end of class
```

config file:

```
$config['url'] = 'stuff'; // config file : foo.php
```

good luck :)

Comment: This is what I was trying but for some reason the config wasn't being passed.

Comment: Did a print_r on the $config var, I found that it was an array with an array called (in this example) 'Foo'. So to access the config vars, you would do something along the lines of `$this->config = $config['foo']; ` and that would be the config for the class Foo... if all of that abstraction makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

To access the variables of config file in your custom library, you can initialize a new CI instance and access the content of config like below:

```
$this->ci = & get_instance();

$configs = $this->ci->config;
```

Now do `var_dump($configs)` to see content of config file.

Comment: Ended up having to go with this option since my config wasn't getting automatically passed and I didn't wanna end up spending hours troubleshooting.

Comment: fair enough, You are binding your class very tightly with CI though, and loose coupling is normally better.

The code I placed below works perfectly on my local host, When you get around to it make sure you trouble shoot it, I think it's important enough to invest your time on.